how to add a fix text to power bi fields value?
I need to add a fix text to a fields value in a column in power bi.
I create a measure such this:
_Budget Amount Text = FactBdg[budget_Amount] & "Dollar"

but the below error happend:
"A single value for column 'budget_Amount' in table 'FactBdg' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."
Can any one help me?

Please edit your question to include data that can be used to reproduce your situation. Add this as text which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this Markdown Tables Generator.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Measures need to return a single value, not a column. The FactBdg[budget_Amount] returns a column in your measure. This will need to be updated with a Min, Max, Sum, etc, to return that single value. Here is how you can fix it:
_Budget Amount Text = SUM(FactBdg[budget_Amount]) & "Dollar"


Thanks, What you suggest If I want to add a fix text to current value of field and show it in card? Rather than a measure

Can you please explain/provide an example of what you mean by "add a fix text to current value of field"?
